# I'm trying to make a POST request on Android studio. However the app stops

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to post, in this case, a "ocorrencia". I'm using retrofit to do it. However everytime I click the button to submit the new "ocorrencia" the app stops.
Here is what I have so far:
     This is my interface

```
   interface Endpoint {

@GET("ocorrencias")
fun getPosts() : Call<List<Ignicoes>>

@POST("ocorrencias")
fun postIgnicao(
    @Field("Latitude")
    Latitude:String,
    @Field("Longitude")
    Longitude:String,
    @Field("Estado")
    Estado:String,
    @Field("DataInicioPropostaIgnicao")
    DataInicioPropostaIgnicao: String,
    @Field("DataDecisaoIgnicao")
    DataDecisaoIgnicao:String,
    @Field("Fotografia")
    Fotografia:String,
    @Field("Azimute")
    Azimute:String

) : Call<Ignicoes>
```

Here is my Ignicoes class:

```
data class Ignicoes(

@SerializedName("Latitude")
var Latitude : String,
@SerializedName("Longitude")
var Longitude : String,
@SerializedName("Estado")
var Estado : String,
@SerializedName("DataInicioPropostaIgnicao")
var DataInicioPropostaIgnicao : String,
@SerializedName("DataDecisaoIgnicao")
var DataDecisaoIgnicao : String,
@SerializedName("Fotografia")
var fotografia : String,
@SerializedName("Azimute")
var azimute : String

  )
```

Here is my NetworkUtils:

```
class NetworkUtils {

companion object {

    /** Retorna uma Instância do Client Retrofit para Requisições
     * @param path Caminho Principal da API
     */
    fun getRetrofitInstance(path : String) : Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(path)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
       }
    }
  }
```

Here is the post function on my class: 
         fun postData(){

```
    val retrofitClient = NetworkUtils
        .getRetrofitInstance("https://localhost:44324/")

    val endpoint = retrofitClient.create(Endpoint::class.java)
    val callback = endpoint.postIgnicao(
        "40.448365",
        "-7.137882",
        "aceite",
        "2423423",
        "sfsdf",
        "fdsfds",
        "32")

    callback.enqueue(object : Callback<Ignicoes> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<Ignicoes>, t: Throwable) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, t.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<Ignicoes>, response: Response<Ignicoes>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(this@AppFogos, "A ocorrência foi enviada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


                }
            }

        }
    })
}
```

I'm not sure why the app stops working. Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: did you add INTERNET_PERMISION in manifest.xml?

Comment: Yes, I made sure I added all the permisions and dependencies

Comment: I have an error saying: " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Field parameters can only be used with form encoding."

Comment: Above your post method put the tag @FormUrlEncoded.  
If it is not working, try to send the data using a hashmap, where the keys are the api attributes